# How do you testfor a specific player 1.11.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a V.I.P. door with a `testfor` to a specific player with this command

```
/testfor @a[name=name,r=radius]
```

I replaced the name with my user and radius with 10 and an error command pops up:

```
 [11:03:47] Data tag parsing failed: Invalid tag encountered, expected '{' as first char.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57917/discussion-on-question-by-austin-how-do-you-testfor-a-specific-player-1-11-2).

Answer (score -2):

You need to use { and } instead of [ and ] and that should work, so hold shift and press the same button that you did before.

The command is:
/testfor @a{name=name,r=radius}
But use the same name and stuff, oh and if you want to make it like a owner only door then only put your name in.

Comment: `[` and `]` as in the question are correct for selector arguments. You may be thinking of NBT, which uses curly brackets.